# Automatically Give All Custom Post Types a Pre-Set Category

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I am building a site with 5 different custom post types on and would like to create an archive page that pulls in all of these posts and then sorts them by the standard WP date order.

Instead of adding this 'all' category manually each time I add a custom post type post, is there anyway of giving a custom post type a custom taxonomy that is created / assigned each time a new post is created? I would then add any additional custom taxonomies manually when I do a post.

To show this 'all' taxonomy I would add a custom taxonomy archive page that would then show all of the custom post types.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a default item to a custom taxonomy?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/how-to-add-a-default-item-to-a-custom-taxonomy)

Answer (score 0):

You can force default terms for a post by using the `save_post` hook. Here's an example from the Developer resources originallly by the user [Aurovrata Venet](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/#comment-2706).

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'set_post_default_category', 10,3 );

function set_post_default_category( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
    // Only want to set if this is a new post!
    if ( $update ){
        return;
    }

    // Only set for post_type = post!
    if ( 'post' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the default term using the slug, its more portable!
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'my-custom-term', 'category' );

    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term->term_id, 'category', true );
}
```

For checking post types you can also use `in_array()` as you have multiple post types.

```
! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'my_post_type_a', 'my_post_type_b', 'my_post_type_n' ) )
```

Another option is to use the post type specific `save_post_{$post->post_type}` hook and attach the same callback function to each of your post types save actions.